# Javascript Subtracting Value Of Input Fields If Checkbox Is Checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have three inputs that are both text and one checkbox.

I would like it to where if the checkbox is checked the value of input A is subtracted from input B and shows up in input C.

I am also wanting it to change if new numbers are entered.

Basically:

1: If checkbox is checked subtract value A from value B.

2: If checkbox is checked subtract value A from value B on keypress.

I've tried this:

```js
$('#autoCal').change(function () {
  var start = +$("#start").val();
  var end = +$("#end").val();
  $("#result").val(end-start);

  if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    $("#end").keyup(function(){
      var start = +$("#start").val();
      var end = +$("#end").val();
      $("#result").val(end-start);
      return;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset data-step="3" data-intro="How many miles did you go? Let us know by filling out this section.">
  <legend>Mileage</legend>
  <label for="oStart"><span>Odometer Start<span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" name="oStart" class="shortInput" id="start"></label>
  <label for="oEnd"><span>Odometer End<span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" name="oEnd" class="shortInput" id="end"></label>
  <label for="mileage"><span>Total Miles<span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" name="mileage" class="shortInput" id="result"></label>
  <label for="autoCal"><span>Auto calculate milage?</span><input type="checkbox" id="autoCal" name="autoCal"></label>
</fieldset>
```

- `autoCal` is the checkbox.
- `start` is value A.
- `end` is value B.
- `result` is value C.

Comment: Can I see some HTML? (I have found the change method unreliable in my case though... and key events on textboxes.) I'm also assuming that the textboxes are for numbers.

Comment: updated to show HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem where it is unable to calculate in the first place. I'm still working on the autocalculate feature.

```
 $('#autoCal').change(function () {
    var start = +$("#start").val();
    var end = +$("#end").val();
    $("#result").val(Number(end) - Number(start));

    if ($(this)[0].checked) {
        $("#start, #end").keyup(function () {
            var start = +$("#start").val();
            var end = +$("#end").val();
            $("#result").val(end - start);
        });
    };
});
```

**EDIT 1**

This is a bit of a quirk, but the expression is a bit wrong. I have updated the code to fix it. (Also add the type="number" to the input, it will not allow letters then)

**EDIT 2**

My bad... I fixed everything though. Your expression is correct, I'm sorry... Have fun!

Comment: :D It took a while though. I was just doing Java for a long time, so javascript is not the norm right now. Lol!